# Get actual package weight from UPS API

Tags: php, api, ups

Is anybody here familiar with the UPS API? I'm trying to figure out how to get the actual package weight from when UPS scanned in the package, I'm using the UPS Tracking api, below I have an example output from the API.

My problem is, it shows the weight that was entered when you created the shipping label and not the actual weight of the package.

Any ideas?

```
Array
(
    [TRACKRESPONSE] => Array
        (
            [RESPONSE] => Array
                (
                    [TRANSACTIONREFERENCE] => Array
                        (
                            [XPCIVERSION] => 1.0
                        )

                    [RESPONSESTATUSCODE] => 1
                    [RESPONSESTATUSDESCRIPTION] => Success
                )

            [SHIPMENT] => Array
                (
                    [SHIPPER] => Array
                        (
                            [SHIPPERNUMBER] => XXXXX
                            [ADDRESS] => Array
                                (
                                    [ADDRESSLINE1] => 1 Main St.
                                    [CITY] => Sometown
                                    [STATEPROVINCECODE] => XX
                                    [POSTALCODE] => 0000   0000
                                    [COUNTRYCODE] => US
                                )

                        )

                    [SHIPTO] => Array
                        (
                            [ADDRESS] => Array
                                (
                                    [CITY] => SOMECITY
                                    [STATEPROVINCECODE] => XX
                                    [POSTALCODE] => 00000
                                    [COUNTRYCODE] => US
                                )

                        )

                    [SHIPMENTWEIGHT] => Array
                        (
                            [UNITOFMEASUREMENT] => Array
                                (
                                    [CODE] => LBS
                                )

                            [WEIGHT] => 33.00
                        )

                    [SERVICE] => Array
                        (
                            [CODE] => 003
                            [DESCRIPTION] => GROUND
                        )

                    [SHIPMENTIDENTIFICATIONNUMBER] => 1ZAXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
                    [PICKUPDATE] => 20130917
                    [PACKAGE] => Array
                        (
                            [TRACKINGNUMBER] => 1ZAXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
                            [ACTIVITY] => Array
                                (
                                    [ACTIVITYLOCATION] => Array
                                        (
                                            [ADDRESS] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [CITY] => SOMECITY
                                                    [STATEPROVINCECODE] => XX
                                                    [POSTALCODE] => 00000
                                                    [COUNTRYCODE] => US
                                                )

                                            [CODE] => M7
                                            [DESCRIPTION] => RECEIVER
                                            [SIGNEDFORBYNAME] => SOMEONE
                                        )

                                    [STATUS] => Array
                                        (
                                            [STATUSTYPE] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [CODE] => D
                                                    [DESCRIPTION] => DELIVERED
                                                )

                                            [STATUSCODE] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [CODE] => KB
                                                )

                                        )

                                    [DATE] => 20130918
                                    [TIME] => 120100
                                )

                            [PACKAGEWEIGHT] => Array
                                (
                                    [UNITOFMEASUREMENT] => Array
                                        (
                                            [CODE] => LBS
                                        )

                                    [WEIGHT] => 33.00
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Answer (score 1):

UPS doesn't output a scanned weight of the package, sorry but you just won't be able to show data they don't provide in their API.

Comment: Oh okay, do you know if they have a more advanced API that would allow this, I've heard of Quantum View, does that allow it?

Comment: I never used Quantum View, so sorry can't help you with that.. Maybe someone else will be able to answer your question. In the meantime go and look if they provide the information you need :)